# Is Microsoft's Office add-in program free for all publishers?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office-store

I have a service where I charge customers for data. I want them to be able to get that data via Excel, but the old VBA addins, which you could distribute with an XLA file, are increasingly being replaced by "[Office Addins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)".

The best way of [distributing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) these appears to be through Microsoft's addins store built into Office. However there is no obvious information in any of Microsoft's [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/) about costs (if any).

- Does Microsoft charge money for free apps on the addins store?
- Does it take commission for apps with in-app subscriptions?
- If yes for the latter, is one able to publish a free addin but charge
  clients externally (as I am currently already doing), thereby avoiding paying any addin store commission?

Comment: I'll try to get some answers internally in Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft does not charge or take a commission for add-ins that you offer through AppSource (aka: the store).

UPDATE: I work at Microsoft and got this from official source. Also see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/appsource-submission-faq#can-i-submit-a-paid-app-to-microsoft-appsource

Comment: May I ask if you have a source for this assertion? Alternatively, are you a Microsoft rep, or could you give us a bit of background on how you know this? Not that I don't believe you but a link to an official place where this is said explicitly, would lend your answer even more cred.